# Decoding JSON and printing some specific part?

Tags: json, python-2.7

I need to take this following URL, get the JSON data, and some how print a certain part of it... For example the "BTC-PCN" part, specifically the "High". Any help? Thanks:

```
import urllib2
import json

response = urllib2.urlopen('https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getmarketsummaries')
data = json.load(response)
data_dump = json.dumps(data)

parsed = json.loads(data_dump)

print parsed['result'][80]
```

For some reason I get a "5e-08".... Thank you very much in advance for your help. :)

Comment: use `data['result']..` no need to call dumps/loads here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the confusion?

`parsed['result'][80]` is:

```
{
    u'Volume': 10864.00514914,
    u'Last': 3e-08,
    u'TimeStamp': u'2014-04-22T01:38:24.103',
    u'High': 5e-08,
    u'MarketName': u'BTC-PCN',
    u'Low': 2e-08,
    u'BaseVolume': 0.00028593
}
```

`u'BTC-PCN'` is the *value* of the `u'MarketName'`:

```
parsed['result'][80]['MarketName'] # u'BTC-PCN'
```

`5e-08` is the *value* of the `u'High'`:

```
parsed['result'][80]['High'] # 5e-08
```

Comment: Thank you, but the number 5e-08 appears for some reason, it is not supposed to be that, if you copy the API link and paste it, search for BTC-PCN you will get "0.000***" and that is the number I needed... For some reason Python changes that..Thank you.